# Isolating A Noisy Component In A Circuit

Tags: power-supply, noise, filtering

I've been working on a project the past couple months or so and I am incorporating an lcd touch screen as an interface for it.  The device is a small digital synthesizer.  The problem I am having is that when I have the screen connected to the circuit, I notice that it produces a great deal of electrical noise on the power rail.  This noise is bleeding into the audio amplifier section of my circuit and making its way into the output audio of the device.  I have filtering on each individual block of my circuit and that has been good up to this point, but it doesn't seem to help this at all.  I'm not sure how to go about solving this.  The only thing I can think of is that I need to somehow isolate either the screen from the rest of the circuit or isolate the block that handles the audio signal.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about this though.

The noise itself is a mix of a lower frequency hum and some high hiss.  I assume this is caused by both the refresh rate of the screen plus the multiplexing of the LEDs.  I don't have a schematic for the actual circuitry of the LCD screen as the manufacturer doesn't seem to provide one

I have some screenshots from my scope for the 5v rail with both the screen disconnected
[image]
and also connected to the circuit.
[image]

Here is a simplified schematic of the circuit I'm using.  I know the power supply section of it could be better, but I'm still learning.  Any help would be appreciated! :D
[image]

Comment: All of the capacitors on the bottom left of your circuit are the wrong way round...

Comment: What causes the 1MHz signal? Is that the touch-screen signal?

Comment: @BeB00 I didn't have a schematic for the current version of the circuit at the time of post, so I quickly altered the old one I had to be representative of the current set up.  I didn't realize I had put the caps on backwards in the schematic, but rest assured they are the correct way in the actual circuit.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, your problem is decoupling (or lack thereof). Try adding a 0.1 uF ceramic to each chip's power pin and the ground plane, with the 5 volt connection as close to the IC as you can manage. Likewise, add a 0.1 uF ceramic to the 3.3 volt supply at the oscillator.

Furthermore, please add a photo of your complete circuit - a *good* picture, too, and not some crappy out-of-focus snapshot from your cell phone. Depending on how you've got things connected to the Arduino, you may well have to modify your ground as well.

Comment: OP may also need 'bulk' value capacitors on the supply rails.

Answer (score 0):

There are two components to interference:

- **Conducted noise** on Power and Return from shared wires to supply from inadequate wiring and decoupling caps and high current lines, also poor ripple on power source from excessive impedance thus poor load regulation

Noise ripple can be ΔV = ΔI * R + I(f) * ωL with wire inductance may also contain false noise from excessively long 10:1 probe ground clip wires.

- **Radiated Noise** from lack of earth ground or lack of twisted pairs or shielding from magnetic switched currents or inadequate shielding. Earth grounding may not be a feasible option but generally improves results due to the low impedance shunting effects.  Ferrite CM chokes are often clamped on noisy DC. Lack of ground planes, power planes with inductive traces too close to signals.

I suggest you start with a better PSU like a PC power supply.